# How to Bundle all required codec in the AVI module?

Tags: c++, codec, avi

I had developed the program that let user record a avi file.

I used vfw.h lib for AVI record and avi codecs option dialog to let user choose what the codecs option need to be used.

This dialog list all AVI codecs that had installed all the computer as MicroSoft Video codec 1, Cinepak,...

If I want to used a codecs as Dix6.1 codecs I have to install this as separate software.

My problem is when I used AVI codecs dialog by AVISaveOption this list all the system codecs and have some codecs not work and have some unnecessary codecs for my application.
In addition to  I must to install Dix or MPEG coecs as separate if I want to use this, this is not advance for my appliction.

So now, I want to ask you if we have any way to bundle all required codecs (as Dix, MPEG1, MPEG4, MS Video Codec 1) to my required codecs I mean I want to list this by my self with own pop up codecs dialog not using AVISaveOptions(hwnd, 0, 1, &m_pAviStream, (LPAVICOMPRESSOPTIONS FAR *) &aopts)  to list and choose the codecs option.

Thanks in advance,

T&T Group!

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is a programmatic way to do this (and there isn't), it's almost certainly **not** a smart idea.

Questions to ask yourself:

- Are those codecs redistributable?
- Do *you* have permission to redistribute them?

Something tells me the folks behind most of these codecs wouldn't take kindly to such redistribution without permission.